# QGIS grass imports vector line data as points, not vector lines

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, contour, dxf

I am very new to QGIS and Grass. I am trying to create a dxf file with height data using Grass 7 as per this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxCxBREEqG0&t=107s). (1:35 mark)

My contour data and Qgis file is uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v4cfoffjkFNpff6cEJELss36soC0FKVN?usp=sharing). When I go to import vector (contours lines) data into GRASS, its view output is in points not vector lines.

Before Import:

[image: Before Import]

After Import:

[image: After Import]

How do I import the vector data into GRASS as vector lines not points. I cannot make height elevations with points I believe.